# TableView not animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I want to animate UIView simultaneously. But my UIView is not animated. Side over lap But my UITableView is not animated.

```
[self.view addSubview:sideview];
[sidevieww setHidden:NO];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [sidevieww setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sidevieww.frame.size.width, sidevieww.frame.size.height)];

    [mytable setFrame:CGRectMake(240,mytable.frame.origin.y,mytable.frame.size.width,mytable.frame.size.height)];
    [mynav setFrame:CGRectMake(240,mynav.frame.origin.y,mynav.frame.size.width,mynav.frame.size.height)];
    [mybutton setFrame:CGRectMake(240, mybutton.frame.origin.y, mybutton.frame.size.width, mybutton.frame.size.height)];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    sideview =true;
}];
```

Comment: Increase time `animateWithDuration` to 1.5.

Comment: You are using AutoLayout. You can't do this. There are hundreds of other questions about this on Stack Overflow so you should be able to find the answer from them.

Comment: i m not using auto layout

Comment: What about the variable name **sideview** and **sidevieww**?

Comment: I'd put money on the fact that you are. You might not **think** you are but I'm certain you are.

Comment: Where do you initialise your `UIView`? As if it is in a storyboard/XIB file, then you are most likely using auto layout, unless you have turned it off in the storyboard configuration. If you're doing it programmatically, could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

That is really not the best way to configure frame.

Replace your code by this one:

```
   [self.view addsubview:sideview];

   [sidevieww setHidden:NO];

    CGRect frameSideVieww = sidevieww.frame;
    frameSideVieww.origin.x = frameSideVieww.origin.y = 0;

    CGRect frameMyTable = mytable.frame;
    frameMyTable.origin.x = 240;

    CGRect frameMyNav = mynav.frame;
    frameMyNav.origin.x = 240;

    CGRect frameMyButton = mybutton.frame;
    mybutton.origin.x = 240;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [sidevieww setFrame:frameSideVieww];
    [mytable setFrame:frameMyTable];
    [mynav setFrame:frameMyNav];
    [mybutton setFrame:frameMyButton];
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    sideview =true;
}];
```

Also, check if your class is subclass of UIViewController.